# pytest can't find module in Lambda function

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, pytest

I have a Lambda, created using the SAM CLI, with a single function. The function itself works just fine (both locally and when deployed) however `pytest` fails, suggesting that my function is unable to import a module within my directory structure.

Note that the directory structure is shown at the bottom of the question.

```sh
# All commands are run from the 'Lambda' directory.
# With the 'sam' commands, the expected message is returned both locally and when deployed.

sam build -u
sam local invoke MyFunction --event events/405-get.json
sam deploy

# But the 'pytest' command fails.

python -m pytest tests/unit -v
```

The only tests I have at present are to ensure that an error is returned when the HTTP method is not `GET`, `DELETE` or `PUT`. The line `from core.exception import MethodNotAllowedException` is indeed at line 2 of 'my-function/app.py', and as mentioned previously, the function is able to import this module without issue when running locally or when deployed to AWS.

Here is the error that `pytest` is encountering.

```sh
my-function/app.py:2: in <module>
    from core.exception import MethodNotAllowedException
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'core'
```

I have tried to move the modules to the same directory as 'app.py' but import still fails.

```sh
my-function/app.py:2: in <module>
    from exception import MethodNotAllowedException
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'exception'
```

I did also try to use relative imports, so I changed line 2 of 'my-function/app.py' to `from .core.exception import MethodNotAllowedException`. However, while `pytest` is now able to import the module, the function itself fails when using `sam local invoke`. So relative imports I believe are a non-starter.

> Unable to import module 'app': attempted relative import with no known parent package

How can I get `pytest` to work with my function?

##### test_handler.py

```py
from proxy import app
import json
import os
import pytest


@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def mock_context(mocker):
    mock_context = mocker.MagicMock()
    mock_context.aws_request_id = '00000000-0000-1000-0000-000000000000'
    return mock_context


@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def event(request):
    dir = '{0}/../../events'.format(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
    name = request.param
    path = '{0}/{1}'.format(dir, name)
    with open(path) as f:
        event = f.read()
    return event


class TestMethodNotAllowed:

    @pytest.mark.parametrize(
        'event', ['405-get.json'], indirect=True)
    def test_405_get(self, event, mock_context):
        '''Test a GET event.'''

        response = app.lambda_handler(json.loads(event), mock_context)
        body = json.loads(response['body'])

        assert response['statusCode'] == 405
        assert 'exception' in body
        assert 'error_message' in body['exception']
        assert body['exception']['error_message'] == 'Method not allowed.'
        assert body['exception']['error_type'] == 'MethodNotAllowedException'
        assert body['exception']['http_method'] == 'GET'

    # Tests for PUT and DELETE also exist.
```

##### File Structure

```
Lambda
├── __init__.py
├── samconfig.toml
├── template.yaml
├── events
|   ├── 405-delete.json
|   ├── 405-get.json
|   └── 405-put.json
├── my-function
|   ├── init.py
|   ├── app.py
|   ├── requirements.txt
|   └── core
|       ├── __init__.py
|       ├── exception.py
|       ├── someotherfile.py
|       └── morefiles.py
└── test
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── requirements.txt
    └── unit
        ├── __init__.py
        └── test_handler.py
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control what's added to `sys.path` using command line options like `--import-mode`. More information can be found at https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/pythonpath.html.

##### edit

If the import modes didn't work perhaps you can try adding the path yourself before the imports in your test, something like

```
import sys
sys.path.append('../../my-function')
...
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but after testing all available `--import-mode` values, I still encounter the same error, that there is no module named `core`.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I had to append to the path using `sys.path.append('{0}/../../my-function'.format(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))`, as this should ensure that the correct directory is appended no matter where the tests are run from. I'm now able to run tests as expected :)